# Weston is not receiving touch input (regarding touch input as mouse input)

Tags: 20.04, touchscreen, wayland, xinput, weston

I connected my computer with a touchscreen. My GNOME applications handles the touch events expectedly except Weston, which regards my touch input as mouse input. I tested touch using `weston-simple-touch`, but nothing is drawn on the interface if I use touchscreen to touch on it.

- OS Name: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
- GNOME version: 3.36.8
- Windowing System: X11
- Weston version: 8.0.0
- `cat ~/.config/weston.ini`:

```
[core]
idle-time=0
require-input=false
xwayland=true

[libinput]
touchscreen_calibrator=true
calibration_helper=/usr/bin/save-calibration.sh
enable-tap=true
tap-and-drag=true
tap-and-drag-lock=true

[shell]
binding-modifier=ctrl
panel-position=none
locking=false
animation=none
close-animation=none
startup-animation=none
auto-zap=true

[terminal]
font=JetBrains Mono
```

- `xinput` (the device with `id=24` is my touchscreen input device):

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MSFT0001:00 06CB:CE2D Mouse               id=28   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MSFT0001:00 06CB:CE2D Touchpad            id=29   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SEMICO USB Keyboard Consumer Control      id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Intuos P M 2 Pen stylus             id=25   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ deltainno Smartisan TNT go Touchpad       id=21   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Intuos P M 2 Pad pad                id=26   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device(8910) Keyboard  id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB OPTICAL MOUSE                         id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ deltainno Smartisan TNT go                id=24   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ deltainno Smartisan TNT go Keyboard       id=20   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ deltainno Smartisan TNT go Mouse          id=23   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=27   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ deltainno Smartisan TNT go Wireless Radio Control id=22   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ SEMICO USB Keyboard Consumer Control      id=31   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ SEMICO USB Keyboard                       id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ SEMICO USB Keyboard System Control        id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ SEMICO USB Keyboard                       id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device(8910) Wireless Radio Control    id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device(8910) Keyboard  id=32   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ICT Camera: ICT Camera                    id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=30   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Generic USB Condenser Microphone          id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ deltainno Smartisan TNT go Keyboard       id=33   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an unsupported feature on X11 backend. See [this issue](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/wayland/weston/-/issues/628).